# Commit/push to bitbucket cloud repository did not show a visible result

Tags: git, push, commit

For maintenance of a Perl legacy web application we use a bitbucket cloud repository to version control the source code of the production system located on a Linux box. Development (on my side) takes place on a Windows 10 box with git bash used to run the git commands. From the last two commit/push sequences directed to the cloud repository only the first one worked (first and the second will refer to the chronological sequence, in which the actions were executed, i.e., the first commit is the second entry in the log output below), i.e. after the first commit/push I found the updated file via the web ui of bitbucket in the main branch.

The second commit/push (of a different file) did not work, the last commit found in the cloud repo was an old one executed by a collegue a long time ago. The messages of both push commands ("git push origin master") were similar, from this it seemed that both push actions were successful, which is not true for the second one (in the sense that the update did not appear in the expected location of the repo).

Since both files reside in the same repo (on the Windows development box) and I cannot find any differences in their status there, I cannot explain, why the first commit/push worked and the second one did not.

But I think one of you guys can help.

Following is the output (modified for data protection reasons) of the git log command:

```
commit 0287f63b9e837c058b027986f6a1f92f4bc5e438 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: John Doe <john_doe@example.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 27 09:58:45 2023 +0200

<another commit>

commit 153571f79499e7caa03cb1edb638c33ca97d4200
Author: John Doe <john_doe@example.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 27 09:28:28 2023 +0200

<a commit>
```

The only relevant difference between the two log messages is the text in the second message, which I cannot interpret:

`(HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)`

Obviously, the solution to the problemn lays behind this bracket's content? Any ideas?

---